# E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-418

Tags: nvidia, error-handling, ppa

My OS is Deepin 15.10. My GPU is NVIDIA Quadro 3000M. I want to play games on Linux. Steam has a program called Proton which enables this. Proton requires `nvidia-418` or higher to work properly, so I tried to download it. This is my attempt:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-418
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-418
```

This seemed strange to me, as numerous websites claimed that this is the way to go. I went looking for any name mismatches in [the very repository itself](http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/n/).

Sure enough, I found a directory named `nvidia-graphics-drivers-418/`, which is *exactly* what I've requested with my `sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-418` terminal command. Here's a screenshot of this directory:

[image]

To make things even more bizzare, I tried downloading *another* directory from this PPA (`nvidia-settings`) *and it worked!*

I don't know what to make of this.

Answer (score 4):

What you're seeing is the name of the directory that holds all of the 418 drivers, not the name of the package itself. To install the 418 driver series, you would run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-418`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this error occurs is because `nvidia-graphics-driver-418` does not support your card—NVIDIA Quadro 3000M. If you go to the [Nvidia website](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx), and search for your card, Nvidia recommends the `nvidia-graphics-driver-390` driver. Unfortunately, it appears that you will not be able to use Steam on that computer. Also, since Deepin is now based on Debian, PPAs are not recommended, as they are designed specifically for Ubuntu.

Comment: The error has nothing to do with card support, it’s related to which packages are listed in whatever `Packages` file is being read as a result of adding the PPA. The last part of your answer is the most important part of all this however and is accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following, its worked for me

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-418`